# JVM process killed by OS

Tags: linux, jvm, out-of-memory, akka

I've implemented a web service using Camel's Jetty component through Akka (endpoint) which forwards received messages to an actor pool with the setup of:

```
   def receive = _route()
   def lowerBound = 5
   def upperBound = 20
   def rampupRate = 0.1
   def partialFill = true
   def selectionCount = 1
   def instance() = Actor.actorOf[Processor]
```

And Processor is a class that processes the received message and replies with the result of the process. The app has been working normally and flawless on my local machine, however after deploying it on an EC2 micro instance (512m of memory - CentOS like OS) the OS (oom-killer) kills the process due to OutOfMemory (not JVM OOM) after 30 calls or so (regardless of the frequency of calls).

Profiling the application locally doesn't show any significant memory leaks, if there exist any at all. Due to some difficulties I could not perform proper profiling on the remote machine but monitoring "top"s output, I observed something interesting which is the free memory available stays around 400mb after the app is initialized, afterwards it bounces between 380mb to 400mb which seems pretty natural (gc, etc). But the interesting part is that after receiving the 30th or so call, it suddenly goes from there to 5mb of free memory and boom, it's killed. The oom-killer log in /var/log/messages verifies that this has been done by the OS due to lack of memory/free swap.

Now this is not totally Akka-relevant but I finally decided I should seek some advice from you guys, after 3 days of hopeless wrestling.

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the JVM heap size?

Comment: Yes I set a 64m hard limit on it, but strangely still gets killed before hitting the JVM limit. Maybe I should try lower amounts?

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that when lot of small objects are created, which should be garbage collected immediately, the Java process is killed. Perhaps because the memory limit is reached before the *temporary* objects are reclaimed by GC.

Try running it with concurrent mark and sweep garbage collector:

```
java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Answer (score 1):

My general observation is that the JVM uses a lot of memory beyond the Java heap. I don't know exactly for what, but can only speculate that it might using normal C heap for compilation or compiled-code storage or other permgen stuff or whatnot. Either way, I have found it difficult to control its usage.

Unless you're very pressed on disk storage, you may want to simply create a swap file of a GB or two so that the JVM has some place to overflow. In my experience, the memory it uses outside the Java heap isn't referenced overly often anyway and can just lie swapped out safely without causing much I/O.